# htaccess Multiple domains in one root running different phps

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to set up an .HTACCESS so I can have multiple domains with the same root directory. I want the htaccess to redirect to a php file dependant on domain name. I don't want to have to set it up per domain - I want it to be for any domain that I set up with the common root directory to redirect to its own php of the same name. eg

mydom1.co.uk will direct to mydom1.php ,

another.co.uk will direct to another.php

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following in your `.htaccess` file at the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST}.php [L,QSA]
```

However, I expect you'll need to amend the main rule to handle the request of different pages. At the moment *everything* will be rewritten to `/domain.php`

Comment: Works perfectly. I don't need to amend the main rule as I use $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] within the php to get the exact url call.